# Hive: Create rows with summed data, by date (unknown number of dates)

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, data-manipulation

I am currently working with a Hive Table which contains transactions data and I need to do some basic statistics on these data, and put the results in a new table.

EDIT: I'm using Hive 0.13 on Hadoop 2.4.1.

**CONTEXT**

First, let me try to present the input table: here's a table with 3 columns, an ID, a date (month/year), and an amount:

```
<ID>     <Date>    <Amount>
 1       11.2014     5.00
 2       11.2014    10.00
 3       12.2014    15.00
 1       12.2014     7.00
 1       12.2014    15.00
 2       01.2015    20.00
 3       01.2015    30.00
 3       01.2015    45.00
...      ...        ...
```

And the desired output consist of a table grouped by IDs, where in each line I sum the the amounts, for each corresponding months:

```
<ID>    <11.2014>   <12.2014>   <01.2015>   <...>
 1       5.00         22.00       0.00       ...
 2       10.00         0.00      20.00       ...
 3       15.00         0.00      75.00       ...
...       ...         ...         ...        ...
```

Considering that the original table has >4 million IDs and > 500 million lines, on more then 2 years. It seems pretty hard to hardcode the table by hand since I don't know how many columns I should create.

(I know how many different dates I have, but if the original table grows over 5, 10, 15 years, there is going to be a lot to do by hand and that's risky.)

**THE CHALLENGE**

I know how to do some basic manipulations and GROUP BYs, I can even do some CASE WHEN, but the tricky part in my problem is that I can not create columns like this (as mentionned above)...

```
SUM (CASE WHEN Date = 11.2014 THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS 11.2014
SUM (CASE WHEN Date = 12.2014 THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS 12.2014
SUM (CASE WHEN Date = 01.2015 THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS 01.2015
SUM (CASE WHEN Date = ???     THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS ???
```

... because I don't know how many different dates I'll eventually have, so I would need something like this:

```
SUM (CASE WHEN Date = [loop over each dates] THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) 
    AS [the date selected in the loop]
```

**THE QUESTION**

Do you have something to propose in order to :

1. How can I loop over all the dates ?
2. And be able to create a colum for every dates I have without specifying myself the name of the soon to be created column ?
3. Is it doable in a single HiveQL script ? (not obligated but could be really nice)

I would like to avoid UDF but at this point I'm not sure it's preventable since I haven't find any case that ressemble mine.

Thanks in advance and don't hesitate to ask for more info.

Comment: In SQL Server, the PIVOT function would do this. What are you using?

Comment: I'm using Hive/Pig 0.13 on a Hadoop (MapR M5) platform 2.4.1. I can run the Hive scripts either in command line or by using HUE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is too long for a comment.

You cannot do exactly what you want in Hive, because a SQL query has to have a fixed number of columns when it is defined.

What can you do?

The easiest thing is simply to change what you want.  Product multiple rows instead of multiple columns:

```
select id, date, sum(amount)
from table t
group by id, date;
```

You can then load the data into your favorite spreadsheet and pivot it there.

Other alternatives.  You can write a query that will write the appropriate query.  This would go through the table, identify the possible dates, and construct a SQL statement.  You can then run the SQL statement.

Or, you could use some other data types, such as a list or JSON to store the aggregated values in one row.

Comment: I like the idea to change what I want! I'll try to produce multiple rows instead of columns. Since I have a huge dataset, I won't be able to pivot the table in a spreadsheet, I would have to also do it in Hive (or maybe Pig). Do you have any tip on this ?